# HTTP Post not returning string array

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, http-post

I am using MVC 4, ASP.NET. I am having an issue of passing checkbox values to my post method in the controller. It returns as null value.

Here's part of my view (Get works and properly fills data):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<fieldset>
        <table>
            <tr>
                @{
                    int cnt = 0;
                    List<LearningEnterprises.ViewModel.AssignedVendor> techs = ViewBag.Tech;

                    foreach (var tech in techs)
                    {
                        if (cnt++ % 3 == 0)
                        {
                            @:</tr><tr>
                        }
                        @:<td>
                            <input type="checkbox"
                               name="selectedTechs"
                               value="@tech.TechID"
                               @(Html.Raw(tech.Assigned ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) />
                               @tech.TechID @:  @tech.Title
                        @:</td>
                    }
                    @:</tr>
                }
        </table>
        <p>
              <input type="submit" value="Save" id="save" />
        </p>
        </fieldset>

}
```

here's my post:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    [HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult EditVendor(int? id, string[] selectedTech)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var vendor = db.Vendors
            .Include(i => i.VendorType)
            .Include(i=>i.Stocks)
            .Where(i => i.ID == id)
            .Single();

        if (TryUpdateModel(vendor, "",
        new string[] { "CompanyName", "PhoneNumber", "Address", "ProvinceState", "City", "Country", "PostalCode", "Email", "numberofBooths", "comments", "electric", "internet", "tonicEquipment", "VendorTypeID" }))
        {
           try
           {
                UpdateVendorTech(selectedTech, vendor);
                db.Entry(vendor).State = EntityState.Modified;

                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
           }

           catch (Exception /* dex */)
           {
                //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
            }
        }
        PopulateAssignedTechData(vendor);
        PopulateDropDownLists(vendor.VendorTypeID);
        return View(vendor);
    }
```

string[] selectedTech is displaying a null value in debug. It is supposed to equal the id value of checkboxes selected in the view.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I can see is that your names mismatch: you have `string[] selectedTech` in your controller but `name = "selectedTechs"` in your view, then the ASP.NET binder being unable to find any values, it sets your array to `null`.

I also note you don't have any post URL in your `Html.BeginForm()` but if you said you could check the value in debug I suppose you are doing it an other way...

Answer (score 0):

I expect that user3426870 is correct and that the problem is to do with the name on the `EditVendor` method signature (`selectedTech`) not matching the name of checkbox on the view (`selectedTechs`).  I suspect that the `DefaultModelBinder` will not be able to match the parameters to bind the values to.

Additionally, the `TryUpdateModel` does not seem to include any properties defined in the view that will be passed in your post request so I suspect that this will not work.

May I suggest some other improvements (which you could research) that you could make:

- The controller method is quite large.  You should look at using
  services/repositories to perform any business logic and database
  calls to reduce the number of actions the controller is performing. 
  This will help to make those smaller parts more testable.
- If the id on the signature should not be null (as you return a bad request if it is) then you should not make it a nullable int? parameter. You will then no longer need to perform that check.

Also, you may wish to add validation to ensure that the id is greater than 0 or that the list of selectedTech has a count that is greater than 0.  Such validation can be performed using data annotations or fluent validation and then a simple check performed in the code such as:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid) { ... }
```

to ensure that the parameters passed in pass your defined validation.

- You should use a view model for the view which holds exactly the
  information that you need.  You can then map between this and your
  lower layer business classes using mapping classes (or automapper). 
  Using a view model is the preferred way and avoids use of ViewBag
  properties.  You can also use some of the HTML helper methods to
  write out some of those view model properties.

Hope these ideas help.